# Multiple boolean variables as function parameters

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, boolean

I have plenty of boolean variables in my code and I want to pass them into a function.

```
public myClass {

         boolean isA, isB, isC, isD, isE, isF, isG;

         // loop to set booleans true or false

         String str = addString(isA, isB, isC, isD, isE, isF, isG);
    }

private String addString(boolean isA, boolean isB, boolean isC, boolean isE, boolean isF, boolean isG) { 
 //code
}
```

The way the program works it will be 2-3 variables true at any point. I want to avoid all those booleans as parameters so I'm considering to pass the true ones into an ArrayList, as :

```
public myClass {

         boolean isA, isB, isC, isD, isE, isF, isG;

         // loop to set booleans true or false

         ArrayList<boolean> list = new ArrayList();

         if(isA) list.add(isA);
         // same check for every variable

         String str = addString(list);
    }

private String addString(ArrayList<boolean>list) { 
      //code
}
```

Is there any better way? I want to know which boolean is passed each time.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Long parameter list is considered a code smell. Wrap all those booleans in a class or a Map and pass that object.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've just added some code.

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use those booleans. You could wrap them in an array and iterate. 
boolean[] vars = {isA,isB,isC,isD,isE,isF,isG};

Comment: Thank you so much @Januson! It works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a variable number of boolean arguments as follow:

```
public void yourMethod(boolean .. booleans) {
    // Your code here
    for (boolean b : booleans) {
        // Doing something with each boolean argument
    }

}
```

And you can call it as follow:

```
yourMethod(true, true, false);
yourMethod(true);
yourMethod(false, false, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is a Builder design pattern.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-design-pattern

TL;DR:

```
String res = new MyStringBuilder(/* any fixed params */)
    .setA(isA)
    .setB(isB)
    // ...
    .build();
```

This will also save you from repeating the booleans you don't care about, eg. you could skip `setA` if it is not relevant to your case, and the default value (say, `false`) is already giving you desired outcome. This also makes code immediately more readable, since `setA` or `setB` names can explicitly represent what gets added (eg. `setAddPrefix`, `setAddHeader`, ...)